# Get user's Facebook email and other detail

Tags: java, android, facebook

Please i want to give my user the option of Signing up with facebook. How can i retrieve the details and feed it to my server for the user's registration
. am using an api to register users to my server. please help:

```
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView loginView;
private LinearLayout signUpButtonParent, loginInButtonParent, signUpRoot, loginRoot;
private View loginBorder,  signUpBorder;
private Button signUpWithEmailButton, loginWithEmailButton,loginFacebook;
LoginButton signUpFacebook;
private SharedPreferenceUtil sharedPreference;


private CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    signUpFacebook =(LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.facebookSignup);
    loginFacebook =(Button) findViewById(R.id.loginFacebook);
    signUpFacebook.setReadPermissions("email","user_photos","user_friends");

    setupViews();


}

private void setupViews() {

    final Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "login_font.ttf");

    loginView.setTypeface(tf);

   signUpFacebook.setOnClickListener(view -> 
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(DashboardActivity.this,Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email")));

    signUpFacebook.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            startActivity(new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "Login was Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "LogIn failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
}




}
```

Interface:

```
public interface ApiService {
  @FormUrlEncoded
@POST("signup")
Observable<StatusItem> signUp(@Field("full_name")String full_name, @Field("phone") String phone, @Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password);
```

}

Comment: Important: Remove your app_id. Reset it asap. Don't share this.

FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this); - This function was deprecated. The Facebook SDK is now auto initialized on Application start. If you are using the Facebook SDK in the main process and don't need a callback on SDK initialization completion you can now remove calls to FacebookSDK.sdkInitialize. If you do need a callback, you should manually invoke the callback in your code.

Aside from that, please share what errors your are receiving and more information as to what this is doing vs. what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult success) {
AccessToken token = success.getAccessToken();
getFBMeData(token);
}



 public void getFBMeData(AccessToken atoken) {
    Profile.fetchProfileForCurrentAccessToken();
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
                                        GraphResponse response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (object != null) {
                        Log.d("FBGraphJSONObject", object.toString());

                       String id =  Profile.getCurrentProfile()
                                .getId();
                       String fName = Profile.getCurrentProfile()
                                .getFirstName();
                        String lName = Profile.getCurrentProfile()
                                .getLastName();
                        String gender = object.optString("gender");
                        String dob = object.optString("birthday");
                        String locationName = "";
                        JSONObject location = object
                                .optJSONObject("location");
                        if (location != null) {
                            locationName = location.optString("name");
                        }
                        String pictureUrl = "", email = "";
                        JSONObject picture = object
                                .optJSONObject("picture");
                        JSONObject data = picture.optJSONObject("data");
                        try {
                            email = URLDecoder.decode(
                                    object.optString("email"), "UTF-8");
                            if (picture != null) {
                                pictureUrl = URLDecoder.decode(
                                        data.optString("url"), "UTF-8");
                            }
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }




                }
            });
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("fields", "gender,email,birthday,location,picture");
    request.setParameters(params);
    request.executeAsync();


}
```